# How can i interpolate a vector on a 2d grid

Tags: python, vectorization

I have generated a 2d grid of length 100 and I have got a vector of tuples which some 2d points.

```
x1 = np.linspace(-1,1,10)
y1 = np.linspace(-1,1,10)
grid=[]
for i in x1:
    for j in y1:
        grid.append((i,j))

#The vector
vec=[(.033,-.22),(.5,-.9),(-.77,-.01),(.5,.2)]
```

What I want is to iterate over all the 100 cells of the grid and wherever the vector tuple is present in that coordinate range, I want `1` against it else `0`. So the output grid will have 4 ones (corresponding to vec) & 96 zeros.

**When I say coordinate range of grid I mean something like this :-

```
ctr=0
for i in x1:
    for j in y1:
        if ctr==0:
            temp=(i,j)
            ctr+=1
            continue
        else:
            print temp, "to" ,i,j
            temp=(i,j)
            ctr+=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the python built-in [bisect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) module to find where your vector fits in the grid:

```
import numpy as np
from bisect import bisect

result = np.zeros(len(grid))
idx = [bisect(grid, x) for x in vec]
result[idx] = 1
```

Comment: But you result has indexed only 3 out of 4 points from the vector. Whereas according to my vector content and the code by @vres the output is `1 : (-0.11111111111111116, 1.0) (0.11111111111111116, -1.0) 
1 : (0.33333333333333326, 1.0) (0.55555555555555536, -1.0) 
1 : (-0.77777777777777779, 1.0) (-0.55555555555555558, -1.0) 
1 : (0.33333333333333326, 1.0) (0.55555555555555536, -1.0) `

Comment: Indeed, since your second and last input vector create the same position in your grid, all indices are returned by bisect, but `result[idx]` only changes one. Hence, 3 out of 4. You can check the output by printing `print([(grid[x-1],grid[x]) for x in idx])`. That is equal.

Comment: good job , let me test it on actual grid :-) . I hope it works for 3d grid also ?? or is there any other library for 3d grids ?

Comment: I have checked it with a 300x300x300 grid as well, and it works fine and very quickly. It takes longest to create the grid with your method - thinking about vectorization (maybe use [`np.meshgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html)?) can further speed it up, you'll have to make the input appropriate for `bisect` again, though, or you can use the numpy function [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html)

Comment: thanks but I explored np.meshgrid but dont know how to use it in my case. Was unable to folow it !!!

Comment: another question : The vector will be assigned to the lower value cell of grid or higher value cell ?

Comment: According to the bisect docs, `bisect` is equivalent to `bisect_right`, thus the returned index will be on the right/higher end. If you want the behavior to be reversed, import and use `bisect_left`.

Comment: just one more question. Im using vectors which are of length between  [2000, 3000] against 3d grid of `200^3`. Even though the vectors are of different length, the bisect is giving me the `result.nonzero()` of same length `99` cells. Is there any limitation in bisect method ?

Comment: as far as the documentation and [source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/bisect.py) goes, `bisect` has two optional arguments, which default to `lo=0` and `hi = len(a)`, with `a` being your input array. No visible limitation there..

Comment: can you try fitting these http://pastebin.ca/3748823, its not wirking for me using your code. Im trying to fit this in a 3d grid 
`x1 = np.linspace(-1,1,10)
y1 = np.linspace(-1,1,10)
z1 = np.linspace(-1,1,10)
grid=[]
for i in x1:
    for j in y1:
  for j in z1:
   grid.append((i,j,k))`

Comment: for me it works fine within 0.005s with the exact code.. you may need to adjust your 3. for-loop to `for k in z1` so you actually use `k` with your `grid` list but otherwise it should work fine. Answer: http://pastebin.ca/3749422

Comment: sorry but can you please check this  http://pastebin.ca/3749718 and let me know what you are getting?

Comment: I updated your pastebin http://pastebin.ca/3749723 with the complete code and at the end you can see the output it produces.